# working Faster-rcnn in cntk c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, machine-learning, cntk

i'm trying to get faster-rcnn model working in C# code.

i have a faster-rcnn trained model that builds and tests in the CNTK python code Below is my attempts to get it working from c#

so far i have:

```
string testImage = @"C:\data\images\mytestimage.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(testImage ));
DeviceDescriptor device = DeviceDescriptor.CPUDevice;

Function modelFunc = Function.Load(modelPath, device);
var inDoims = modelFunc.Arguments;
Variable inputVar = modelFunc.Arguments.FirstOrDefault();
Variable inputVar2 = modelFunc.Arguments[1];


NDShape inputShape = inputVar.Shape;
int imageWidth = inputShape[0];

int imageHeight = inputShape[1];
int imageChannels = inputShape[2];
int imageSize = inputShape.TotalSize;

bitmap = ImageProcessing.Resize(bitmap, imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
var pixels = ImageProcessing.ParallelExtractCHW(bitmap);

Variable input = modelFunc.Arguments[0];
var inputDataMap = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>();


List<float> input2Vals = new List<float>();

input2Vals.Add(imageWidth);
input2Vals.Add(imageHeight);
input2Vals.Add(imageWidth);
input2Vals.Add(imageHeight);
input2Vals.Add(imageWidth);
input2Vals.Add(imageHeight);

Value inputVal = Value.CreateBatch(inputVar.Shape, pixels, device);
Value inputValue2 = Value.CreateBatch(inputVar2.Shape, input2Vals, device);

inputDataMap[input] = inputVal;
inputDataMap[inputVar2] = inputValue2;

NDShape outputShape1 = modelFunc.Outputs[0].Shape;
NDShape outputShape2 = modelFunc.Outputs[1].Shape;
NDShape outputShape3 = modelFunc.Outputs[2].Shape;
Value outputValue1 = null;
Value outputValue2 = null; ;
Value outputValue3 = null; ;

var outputDataMap = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>() 
{ 
   { modelFunc.Outputs[0], outputValue1 }, 
   { modelFunc.Outputs[1], outputValue2 }, 
   { modelFunc.Outputs[2], outputValue3 }
};

//run the model
modelFunc.Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, device);

var out0 = outputDataMap[modelFunc.Outputs[0]];
var out1 = outputDataMap[modelFunc.Outputs[1]];
var out2 = outputDataMap[modelFunc.Outputs[2]];



var clsPred = out0.GetDenseData<float>(modelFunc.Outputs[0])[0];
var rois = out1.GetDenseData<float>(modelFunc.Outputs[1])[0];
var vbboxR = out2.GetDenseData<float>(modelFunc.Outputs[2])[0];

  var labels = new[] { "__background__", "firstobject", "secondobject", "thirdsobject"};

....
```

}

but the results I get back in clsPred don't make any sense...for example when my test image is completely blank...the model seems to think there are objects in it....
Has anyone any recommendations?

Buzz